# Searching within QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, search

In QGIS 2.4 when opening an attibute table, it does not have any clear "look for" search bar as seen in older versions in screenshots and videos. There is now a (SQL?) query builder that takes much longer to operate than a simple search bar.

How to efficiently search within an attribute table with QGIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is under the "Show all features" Button:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great thank you! Just tested it and it does exactly what I needed it to do. Not sure if it is the exact same feature as the old search bar but you can filter results quickly and save them as new shp files and color them differently, etc.

Comment: does this filter work with 'or' operators? if so, how?

Comment: More "complex" searches, you will need to use the advanced filter option and use and expression like: "name" = 'something' or "name" = 'something else'